# How can I implement user input to determine how many cards the user is dealt?

Tags: java

I'm making a game for a school project where the user must guess how many cards they can be dealt in order to have the values of the cards get as close as possible to a specified target number. I currently can deal the users cards based on a predetermined value, but need to change this so that the users input will deal them the number of cards that they desire. I've attached my deck class as well as the actual game class. Thanks in advance.

Deck class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {

    private static final int NUMCARDS = 52;
    private final Card[] CARDS = new Card[52];
    private int cardIndex;

    public Deck() {
        for (int thisCard = 0; thisCard < NUMCARDS; thisCard++) {
            this.CARDS[thisCard] = new Card(thisCard % 13, thisCard / 13);
        }
        this.cardIndex = NUMCARDS - 1;
        this.shuffle();
    }

    private void shuffle() {
        int index;
        Card temp;

        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = this.CARDS.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
            temp = this.CARDS[index];
            this.CARDS[index] = this.CARDS[i];
            this.CARDS[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    public Card deal() {
        return this.CARDS[this.cardIndex--];
    }
}
```

Game class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CardGame {

    private static final int NUMCARDS =5;
    private Card[] player1 = new Card[NUMCARDS];
    private Card[] player2 = new Card[NUMCARDS];

    public CardGame() {
        Deck deck = new Deck();

        for (int i=0; i<NUMCARDS; i++) {
            this.player1[i] = deck.deal();
            this.player2[i] = deck.deal();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CardGame game = new CardGame();

        Scanner player1Name = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter player 1 name");

        String p1Name = player1Name.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Welcome " + p1Name);

        Scanner cardNum = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many cards : ");

        int cardNo = cardNum.nextInt();

        cardNum.close();



        System.out.println("Target is 51");
        System.out.println("");

        for (int i = NUMCARDS-1; i>=0; i--) {
            System.out.println(p1Name + ": " + game.player1[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a new param to the `deal()` method, say `deal(int count)`, which is used to deal a certain number of cards.

Answer (score 0):

To change the number of dealed cards to the number of cards that the user desires. You could overload your methode deal()
by a method of the same name with a paramater or argument. Then the new mehtode `deal(int number)` can be controlled by the argument/parameter number. Finally it returns you an array or collection of selected dealed cards. Furthermore here:

### Some Recommendations

1. The administration of a growing and shrinking array is not easy and shoudn't be your job so it would make you work a lot easier if there would exist a collection which does that for you. You're lucky there is a Collection which does exeactly this for you called ArrayList/LinkedList. So you implementation could be like this: `private final LikedList<Card> Cards = new LinkedList<>();`
2. If you use the LinkedList instate of your are you get some nice methode for free. You can fill the List by the method add(...). The shuffeling of it could be done by Collections.shuffel(Cards). Also you deal() method could be more simple. The Collection LinkedList  has a Methode which gives you immediately the first element and sorts the rest for you. This mehtod is could poll().

At the end your methode would look like this.

```
public Card deal() {
    //this method retrieves and removes the head (first element) of your card list 
    return cards.poll();
}
```

and your new methode could look like this

```
public List<Card> deal(int number) {
    List<Card> result = new ArrayList<>(number);
    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
        result.add(deal());
    }
    //returns you a List of cards 
    return result;
 }
```